# jQuery Events Triggering after others

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I need an event/events that will do the following:
After user selects text/DOM element, and drags it back and fourth, I need a function to run.
How can I do so smoothly?
(jQuery)

Comment: @gdoron I created a mousedown then in it an event of a drag.

Comment: Check jQuery ui draggabl widget. Don't do it by your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery draggable http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

```
$("#what-will-be-dragged" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
      //this will run when the dragging stops
   }
});
```

Comment: And while it is dragged? + can I get the HTML of the DOM element dragged?

Comment: You would add another event `drag: function(event, ui) { //execute this while draggin }`. You can get the jQuery object with `$(this)` within these functions, or if you want the html then `$(this).html()`.